# Running bs4Dash shiny example - unused argument

Tags: r, shiny, bs4dash

I am running the following snippet of code from the bs4Dash [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bs4Dash/versions/0.2.0/topics/bs4DashPage):

```
 library(bs4Dash)

 shiny::shinyApp(
   ui = bs4DashPage(
    navbar = bs4DashNavbar(),
    sidebar = bs4DashSidebar(),
    controlbar = bs4DashControlbar(),
    footer = bs4DashFooter(),
    title = "test",
    body = bs4DashBody()
   ),
   server = function(input, output) {}
 )
```

but I am getting this error:

```
Warning: Error in bs4DashPage: unused argument (navbar = bs4DashNavbar())
  64: force
  63: uiHttpHandler
  62: shiny::shinyApp
   1: runApp
```

...any idea what the deal is here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`navbar` argument has been removed and you need to pass it into `header`.

```
library(bs4Dash)

shiny::shinyApp(
    ui = bs4DashPage(
        header = bs4DashNavbar(title = "My Shiny app"),
        sidebar = bs4DashSidebar(),
        controlbar = bs4DashControlbar(),
        footer = bs4DashFooter(),
        title = "test",
        body = bs4DashBody()
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {}
)
```